# Objective-C : Can't set NSMutableDictionary from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to retrieve an NSDictionary that was saved to NSUserDefaults. When I log out what I'm trying to retrieve, it displays correctly:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"userdetails"] mutableCopy]);
```

However, when I try to assign to a variable, it returns as nil.

```
NSMutableDictionary *test123 =  [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"userdetails"] mutableCopy];
```

Any idea why?

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns as nil."?

Comment: Are these two lines one right after the other or in two different places in your code?

Comment: test123 = nil after 'NSMutableDictionary *test123 =  [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"userdetails"] mutableCopy];'

Comment: @rmaddy one after another. the assignment doesn't work without the log either, I just added that to test

Comment: What if you add `NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"userdetails"];`. Is that `nil`?

Comment: @rmaddy yeah, also nil

Comment: Is it possible that one time or another, you might have some unprintable Unicode characters or something in your `@"userdetails"` string or something else that makes it appear to be the same string without actually being identical? What happens if you make that an `NSString * const` constant instead and use the constant in both the log and the assignment? Do you still have non-identical results?

Comment: did you [defaults synchronize] after you set the dictionary?

Comment: I have added my working code

Answer (score 0):

Check with my working code,

Save like this,

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourMutableDictionary];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"currentUser"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

Get dictionary ,

```
 NSData *dictionaryData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentUser"];
 NSDictionary *tempDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dictionaryData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try it use the following code:

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:(NSDictionary *)yourDictionary forKey:yourkey];`